# One-line iteration and output in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

How would one iterate through a collection and output an attribute in one line in ERB?

I've tried the following, but that outputs the whole object:

```
<%= Post.all.each {|p| (content_tag :div, p.title)} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nmeylan pointed that calling Post.all in view is not a good practice.

I would use @posts as example below. You could try:

```
<%= @posts.map { |p| content_tag :div, h(p.title) }.join.html_safe %>
```

Since rails 4 escape HTML by default, you have to call `html_safe` or `raw`. But it seems like p.title is a user input, so it has to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling an ActiveRecord method (Post.all) in your view, it's a bad practice, call it in your controller.

Then, to answer your question I would use the [content_tag_for method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag_for) or [div_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for)